# Symfony2 optional ordered parameters

Tags: php, symfony, search

So, we have this situation, this WEIRD and UNNECESARY situation, but our SEO team wants it, so we must swallow.

We need to pass our search filters as URL parts instead of just querystrings (which would be the obvious and normal thing).

Let's say we have three filters

`gender` `age` and `location`

Well, like in any search with filters, we cann have all filters enabled or none.

In a normal scenario, this would be `/search?gender=female&age=25&location=london`, on our strange scenario it ould be `/search/female/25/london`

But as I said we can have all or none `/search` would be `/search` (yep)

That's easy, just a `Controller` with a `SearchAction($gender, $age, $location)` and a routing `/search/{gender}/{age}/{location}`

But let's say, we only want to search `female` and `london`

**oops!** our routing, controller and action won't feet our needs, because `{age}` is needed, and we aren't using it.

We have the same problem if we try to search genderless people with 25 `age` and located in `london` well, it won't work neither, we need a `{gender}` `/search/25/london`

Of course, we don't want to be able to load `/search/25/london/female` because we want an order in our filters, but ordered so we don't have duplicated content, you know, SEO stuff...

So that's our situation, we need a controller's action, which can handle `n` parameters (we've count 5 by now) which will be our search filters, in a specific order but optional at the same time...

So now are a bit lost on this. We have defined that we want the order, we want the filters, and we want them to be optional, so the "easy" thing is that we know that the first parameter will always be the `{gender}` but it can be optional, so if `null` we will just ignore it on the DB query.

I do not provide code because what we've done is not even close to our goal, it's just an array of optional parameters and a bunch of useless code, it was just a draft.

We can make a routing for each case, and let the hierarchy handle it if missing parameters, but of course what I am asking if there's a possible and good looking way to do this using the less amount of lines possible, because you know, code must be good to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

In the past i approach this problem with something like:

```
/search/gender/{gender}/age/{age}/location/{location}
```

that could accept also a null --> any value like:

```
 /search/gender/male/age/any/location/london
```

Hope this help

Comment: Another approach is to just have three optional parameters then figure out which is which by analyzing the content.  Very skeptical that seo really needs this.

Comment: Well, SEO says they need this, we don't need it, they're just filters goddamn. Your solution @Matteo is not valid for what they want because we can't use `/location`, they said that we must use `/london` directly...

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to do this (and you're right that it sounds bad) then I would build it the way you think is right (with the optional parameters - let's call this `searchAction`) but then create an action for each possible scenario and use the internal forwarding to direct to the `searchAction`

For example you could have a route defined `search/{gender}/{age}` and which only matches when age is an integer. Then inside this action you could forward to your main search passing the arguments from your action as parameters to the `searchAction`.

```
return $this->forward(
  'MyBundle:Search:search', [], ['gender' => $gender, 'age' => $age]
);
```

Then repeat for `/search/{gender}/{age}/{location}`, `/search/{gender}/{location}` etc.

Answer (score 0):

May Be approached from the other side will be simplier. 
You could make search route as '/search/allGender/allAge/allLocation' for case without search word. If user want to search Age 25 it will be '/search/allGender/25/allLocation'... 
Just ignore "reserved' words ('allGender','allAge','allLocation') on the DB query.
I think your SEO team will be satisfied by this solution. And it's very easy for realization